# "Unable to find python module." printing several times in Visual Studio terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Trying to install and use VS for python, with the python, pylance, and isort extensions installed.  I've run into this problem trying a simple print("This is a test") program:

```
PS C:\Users\jonze\VSPyWorkspace>  & 'C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe' 'c:\Users\jonze\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '55072' '--' 'c:\Users\jonze\VSPyWorkspace\testerFIle.py'

Unable to find python module. 
Unable to find python module. 
Unable to find python module. 
Unable to find python module. 
Unable to find python module. 
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
This is a test
Unable to find python module.
```

Does anyone know what is causing those errors to pop up?  Any help would be appreciated.

Tried uninstalling/reinstalling VS, uninstalling/reinstalling all extensions for VS, and did the pip install python ect to the ends of the earth.  Stack Overflow is also not letting me post pictures yet (new user), so there's a link if you need another visual.

Comment: This sounds a lot like either a PATH environment variable issue, or your python interpreter not being selected correctly in VSC.  How did you go about installing python?  Can you run python scripts form the command prompt?  If you open command prompt, what do you get if you run `echo %path%`? do you see any locations that look like where you installed python?

Comment: Yes, after running echo %path% in the command prompt it looks like there are a few paths that have python on them.  Should I delete those paths?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the python interpreter if you have installed python.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.Check if your local Python version is the same as vscode's in the status bar.If not, click it in vsc and select the correct version.